# I Have been trying to Store some data as JSON but now i am having trouble reading and displaying the stored JSON. Please Guide me

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-10

This is the Model where I insert, am I doing it correctly?

```
public static function insertPlotDetails($data){
    $PlotDetails = array();
        $PlotDetails['L_Name'] = $data['Plot'];
        $PlotDetails['L_Owner'] = $data['Owner'];
        $PlotDetails['L_Spice'] = $data['Spice'];
        $PlotDetails['L_AreaAcre'] = $data['Area'];
        $PlotDetails['L_AreaHa'] = 0;
        $PlotDetails['L_ProducedAmt_Kg'] = $data['PdAmount'];
        $PlotDetails['L_District'] = $data['District'];
        $PlotDetails['L_Block'] = $data['Block'];
        $PlotDetails['L_Village'] = $data['Village'];
        $PlotDetails['lat'] = $data['Latitude'];
        $PlotDetails['lng'] = $data['Longitude'];
        $PlotDetails['img'] = $data['ImageUpload'];
        $PlotDetails['PdArea_JSON'] = json_encode(["'TotalProduction': {'PlotName': '".$data['Plot']."','Area':[{'Name': 'Main','Variant':[{'IISR_Varada': ''".$data['IISR_Varada']."'','IISR_Mahima': '".$data['IISR_Mahima']."','Nadia_Nagaland': '".$data['Nadia_Nagaland']."','Nadia_Odisha': '".$data['Nadia_Odisha']."','Karbi': '".$data['Karbi']."','Local': '".$data['Local']."' } ] },{'Name': 'Trial','Variant': [ {'IISR_Varada': '".$data['T_IISR_Varada']."','IISR_Mahima': '".$data['T_IISR_Mahima']."','Nadia_Nagaland': '".$data['T_Nadia_Nagaland']."','Nadia_Odisha': '".$data['T_Nadia_Odisha']."','Karbi': '".$data['T_Karbi']."','Local': '".$data['T_Local']."' } ] } ]} }"]);

           

        try {

            $PlotDetails_response =  DB::table('locationdb')->insert($PlotDetails);
            
          
          } catch (\Exception $e) {
          
              return $e->getMessage();
          }
    //    
   
    return $PlotDetails_response;

}
```

This is how I get The Data and try to access the JSON.

```
public function GetJsonTest()
{
    $data= MapModel::GetJsonTest();
   
   $json = $data[0]->PdArea_JSON;
   $array = json_decode($json, true);
   dd($json->TotalProduction->);

}
```

My Intention was to be able to read the index of like 'Name' and 'Variety'. It is outputting as string and I cannot find a way to convert it back to array or Object so that I can read and display.

```
["'TotalProduction': {'PlotName': 'TestJson','Area':[{'Name': 'Main','Variant':[{'IISR_Varada': ''10'','IISR_Mahima': '12','Nadia_Nagaland': '13','Nadia_Odisha': '14','Karbi': '15','Local': '16' } ] },{'Name': 'Trial','Variant': [ {'IISR_Varada': '11','IISR_Mahima': '12','Nadia_Nagaland': '13','Nadia_Odisha': '14','Karbi': '15','Local': '16' } ] } ]} }"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```php
$PlotDetails['PdArea_JSON'] = json_encode(["'TotalProduction': {'PlotName': '".$data['Plot']."','Area':[{'Name': 'Main','Variant':[{'IISR_Varada': ''".$data['IISR_Varada']."'','IISR_Mahima': '".$data['IISR_Mahima']."','Nadia_Nagaland': '".$data['Nadia_Nagaland']."','Nadia_Odisha': '".$data['Nadia_Odisha']."','Karbi': '".$data['Karbi']."','Local': '".$data['Local']."' } ] },{'Name': 'Trial','Variant': [ {'IISR_Varada': '".$data['T_IISR_Varada']."','IISR_Mahima': '".$data['T_IISR_Mahima']."','Nadia_Nagaland': '".$data['T_Nadia_Nagaland']."','Nadia_Odisha': '".$data['T_Nadia_Odisha']."','Karbi': '".$data['T_Karbi']."','Local': '".$data['T_Local']."' } ] } ]} }"]);
```

where it appears you have attempted to create a multi-level array but have actually just got an array with a single string in it. You should change that to json_encode an *actual* array:

```
$PlotDetails['PdArea_JSON'] = json_encode(array (
  'TotalProduction' => 
  array (
    'PlotName' => $data['Plot'],
    'Area' => array (
      array (
        'Name' => 'Main',
        'Variant' => array (
          array (
            'IISR_Varada' => $data['IISR_Varada'],
            'IISR_Mahima' => $data['IISR_Mahima'],
            'Nadia_Nagaland' => $data['Nadia_Nagaland'],
            'Nadia_Odisha' => $data['Nadia_Odisha'],
            'Karbi' => $data['Karbi'],
            'Local' => $data['Local'],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      array (
        'Name' => 'Trial',
        'Variant' => array (
          array (
            'IISR_Varada' => $data['T_IISR_Varada'],
            'IISR_Mahima' => $data['T_IISR_Mahima'],
            'Nadia_Nagaland' => $data['T_Nadia_Nagaland'],
            'Nadia_Odisha' => $data['T_Nadia_Odisha'],
            'Karbi' => $data['T_Karbi'],
            'Local' => $data['T_Local'],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```

When you `json_decode` this, you will be able (for example) to access `$json->TotalProduction->Area[0]->Variant[0]->Karbi`.

Comment: Thank you very much , this is how i wanted it to be . This is my first time trying to save as a JSON format and your answer is very helpful.

Comment: @ShailangKharsati no worries - I'm glad I could help